# why am i seeing TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete' error even though i used on_delete?

Tags: django-models

I am doing a course in django and this is the models.py code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here

class Game(models.Model):
    first_player = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = "games_first_player")
    second_player = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = "games_second_player")
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Move(models.Model):
    x = models.IntegerField()
    y = models.IntegerField()
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    by_first_player = models.BooleanField()
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
```

Even though i used on_delete keyword argument, I am seeing below error message when i run makemigrations :

```
(dev) D:\django\projects\tictactoe>python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 15, in
<module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "D:\django\projects\dev\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py",
line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()   File "D:\django\projects\dev\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py",
line 347, in execute
    django.setup()   File "D:\django\projects\dev\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line
24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)   File "D:\django\projects\dev\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py",
line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()   File "D:\django\projects\dev\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line
198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)   File "D:\django\projects\dev\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in
import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import   File
"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load   File
"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked  
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in
exec_module   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in
_call_with_frames_removed   File "D:\django\projects\tictactoe\gameplay\models.py", line 6, in <module>
    class Game(models.Model):   File "D:\django\projects\tictactoe\gameplay\models.py", line 7, in Game
    first_player = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = "games_first_player") TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required
positional argument: 'on_delete'
```

Comment: first_player = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = "games_first_player", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    second_player = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = "games_second_player", on_delete=models.CASCADE) - Resolved this by updating above two statements.

Comment: Edit your question instead of adding comments.

Answer (score 0):

when ever you use `models.ForeignKey` you should pass the argument `on_delete=models.CASCADE`

Comment: check other classes and make migrations then re run the surver